# sqlite SELECT statement returns None

Tags: python, database, sqlite, select, nonetype

I have an issue returning a string from my database query.
First step was to create a database:

```
def create_database():

    # database setup
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('db/mydb.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, balance REAL NOT NULL, text TEXT NOT NULL)')
        con.commit()
        con.close()
    except Error as e:
        print('Failed to setup database.\n' + e)
        exit(1)

def get_connection():

    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('db/mydb.db')
        return con
    except:
        print('Unable to connect to database. Please try again later.\n')
        exit(1)
```

My second step was creating a user and add him with `INSERT` to my database:

```
def create_user(user_id : int):

    balance = 0.0; # base unit = USD
    text = create_text()

    # connect to database
    con = get_connection()
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute('INSERT INTO user (id, balance, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (user_id, balance, text))

    database = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM user').fetchone()
    print(database)
    
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def create_text():

    # do some stuff which creates my text
    # the text is something like 'LNURL...'
    
    return text
```

This is how the result of my database query looks like:

```
(393120847059091456, 0.0, 'LNURL1DP68GURN8GHJ7URP09JX7MTPDCHXGEF0D3H82UNVWQHKZURF9AMRZTMVDE6HYMP0XGMQA9V7RT')
```

If I try to query this database for my `text` it returns nothing/`None`. My `print(text)` just produces an empty new line.

```
def get_text(user_id : int):

    # connect to database
    con = get_connection()
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute('SELECT text FROM user WHERE id=?', (user_id,))
    text = cur.fetchone()

    con.commit()
    con.close()

    print(text)
    return text
```

Comment: Your code runs fine. Post the code that you use to test it.

Comment: @forpas I edited my post and attached some screenshots.

Comment: The website you linked to is buggy, it doesn't show SQLite's integers correctly, likely the value you have in your database is some other value than shown, use `select cast(id as 'text') from user;` to see the correct value, or use something like the official SQLite shell.

Comment: As I said your code works fine. But are you sure that you are querying the same table that you created? The INSERT statement contains a column `lnurl` which does not exist in the table.

Comment: thanks, that was a typo by my side. I will double check everything

Comment: My integer is `>2^32` but `<2^64`. Does my database use 64bit as default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my sqlite database used 32bit int values by default. So forcing it to use 64 bit when creating the table fixed my issue:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id INT8 PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, balance REAL NOT NULL, text TEXT NOT NULL')
```

Than I can return my result of the query with this: `return text[0]`

Comment: There is no INT8 data type in SQLite (although it does not throw any error) as you can see here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html Also in this link, it is mentioned for INTEGER that: *The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.* The difference between `INT8 PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` and `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` is that the latter defines an autoincremented integer column for which SQLite does forces data type checking.

Comment: great, so using `PRIMARY KEY` was my mistake. removing it and changing `INT8` to `INTEGER` solved it, thanks.

Comment: I don't believe `PRIMARY KEY` was the problem. As I mentioned in my comments your code worked fine as it was. I don't know why you got None because I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: ok, strange than. maybe it is because of my IDE or os specific (win10 64 bit). for now it is fixed for me.